# Security Log - Overcrossing Maximum size limit

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log

Please check the below print-screen. I have limit maximum log size at 80 MB, still the log size has gone till 10 GB, Why? 
do you have any idea, why it is happening and how to limit to 80 MB.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft:

> If you set a maximum log size that is smaller than the current size of
>   the log, the maximum size will not be enforced until after the log is
>   cleared.

So I'm assuming you set the maximum size after the log had already exceeded it. Clearing the log should resolve this.